# Configure systemd NTP to set TAI offset

Tags: time, ntp

"New" kernel versions (since Linux 2.6.26) support [TAI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Atomic_Time) clock, but systemd implementation on Ubuntu (18.04 LTS in my case) seems to ignore it.

How can I configure systemd NTP to mantain TAI offset updated and correct?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the UTC and TAI is a file that holds leapseconds. See the contents of `/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list`. systemd has(/should have?) no impact on this.

You need to configure NTP to include it (note: NTP v4.2.6 changed the way on how the leapfile is used). See the [Ubuntu NTP manual section5](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/ntp.conf.5.html) and the "leapfile" option.  From the manual page for NTP:

> leapfile `leapfile`
>
> This command loads the NIST leapseconds file and initializes the leapsecond values for the next leapsecond time, expiration time and TAI offset. The file can be obtained directly from NIST national time servers using ftp as the ASCII file `pub/leap-seconds.list`.
>
> The leapfile is scanned when ntpd processes the leapfile directive or when ntp detects that leapfile has changed.  ntpd checks once a day to see if the leapfile has changed.

So that could be adding to `/etc/ntpd.conf` something like this:

```
leapfile /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list
```

See also the man page  for [update-leap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/update-leap.1.html).

> update-leap will validate the file currently on the local system and if necessary, updates leap-second definition file. Ordinarily, the file is found using the "leapfile" directive in ntp.conf(5).  However,  an alternate location can be specified on the command line.

Mind that this breaks POSIX compliance as it will introduce times like "23:59:60".

Comment: Ubuntu doen't use `ntpd` by default. If possible I want to use default services.

Comment: As an off-topic comment, how can this break POSIX compliance? You only can access TAI time using `clock_gettime()` flag `CLOCK_TAI`. In the same way, you only will see "weird" behavior during a leap second change when you use `CLOCK_UTC` flag. All other flags and system calls remain POSIX compatible.

Comment: @user3368561 because of the example I gave. TAI will make times like 23:59:60 possible. That is an invalid timestamp in UTC if a file is saved at exactly that moment.

Comment: TAI is atomic time, not UTC. How can it be affected by leap seconds? Moreover, any sensible implementation of leap seconds will progressively drift the internal clock to accommodate the leap second instead of jumping a whole second at once.

Comment: @user3368561 "The current version of UTC is defined by International Telecommunications Union, and is based on TAI with leap seconds added at irregular intervals to compensate for the slowing of Earth's rotation. Leap seconds keep UTC within 0.9 second of universal time."